# Why does Step (-1) give me an application-defined or object-defined error, but not step (-2)

Tags: excel, vba, loops

So I've got my code that goes in a loop and counts 1 if there's a specific status with a corresponding date. Usually the format would go like this : status, date, status, date, status, date  etc...

However, my data set has changed to become status, date, person, status, date, person, status, date, person etc...

I was previously using step (-2) as, but now when I change to step (-1) or even step (-3), it gives me an application-defined or object-defined error.

Anyone have any clue why that is?

```
Sub CheckDates()


Dim count As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer


Sheets(1).Select

lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

'have to keep data in a table for this to actually work as it ctrls+left to the table, which will end where the very last text of any row is
lastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column


count = 0
i = 2
j = lastColumn

For i = 2 To lastrow
For j = lastColumn To 1 Step (-1)
If Sheet1.Cells(i, j) < Sheet2.Cells(1, 1) And Sheet1.Cells(i, j - 1) = "Reçu" Then
    count = count + 1
    GoTo NextIteration
End If
Next j
NextIteration:
Next i

Sheet2.Cells(1, 7) = count

Sheets(2).Select

Call DeleteSAC
'Runs the DeleteSAC Macro


End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of Goto NextIteration usually Exit For is used. Is ActiveSheet a third sheet or is it actually Sheet1?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this line
`If Sheet1.Cells(i, j) < Sheet2.Cells(1, 1) And Sheet1.Cells(i, j - 1) = "Reçu" Then`

if j = 1, then j-1 will be 0 and you get the error (i.e. no column 0 exists)

with `Step -2` you don't get error because (if I have to guess) the number of columns is even, i.e. the last value of j would be 2. on next iteration j will be 0 and loop body will not be executed at all, thus no error.

Comment: Mm, I see.. is there any work around for this? I was under the impression that if I got to the first column in my row, then it would loop on to the 3rd row and so on and so forth.

Comment: I would suggest to print i and j before the if, for each iteration, so you will see what's going on. There are better ways to do it, but with minimum changes - I think `For j = lastColumn-1 To 2 Step -3`. I assume first column with date is B, i.e. column 2.